# What are my options in terms of getting Heroku traffic metrics?

Tags: heroku

I am interested in obtaining as much information about the website's traffic as possible (number of visitors, average bounce rate, average visit length etc). What are my options for Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

You can add Google Analytics to templates regardless of the way you host your application.  That's probably the most straightforward option.